# Firmware Upgrade Encountered

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, odin

I am in the process of restoring a Samsung Galaxy S4, for Verizon. It shows a screen
that says I need to use the "Software Repair Assistant"program. Could anyone please provide assistance as to how I can resolve this issue?